# Sequelize and querying on complex relations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to understand how best to perform a query over multiple entities using Sequelize and Node.js.

I have defined a model "User" which has a belongsToMany relation with a model "Location". I then have a model "Asset" which also has a belongsToMany relation with "Location". When I have an instance of a User I would like to fetch all Assets that are associated with Locations that the User is associated with.

I tried the following which doesn't seem to work...

```
user.getLocations().then(function(userLocations) { return Asset.findAll({ where: { "Locations" : { $any : userLocations } }) })
```

Could anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
User.findById(user_id, {
    include: [{
        model: Location,
        required: true
    }]
}).then(user => Asset.findAll({
    where: {
        user_id: user.id,
        location_id: {
            $in: user.locations.map(location => location.id)
        }
    }
})).then(assets => {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This put me in the right direction. In addition to this I had to explicitly specify "as" in the "include" since I had specified "as" when defining the relation. Also since I had a one to many relation between asset and locations I had to include locations when querying the assets. I'll attach the final query as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was the final result...

```
User.findById(user_id, {
    include: [{
        model: Location,
        as: 'Locations', // Was needed since the original relation was defined with 'as'
        required: true
    }]
}).then(user => Asset.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Location,
        as: 'Locations',
        where: {
            id: {
                $in: user.Locations.map(location => location.id)
            }
        }
    }]
})).then(assets => {
    // The rest of your logic here...
});
```